# leaflet geodesic - larger dataset doesn't show up

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, leaflet

I'm using the following:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "/geojson/routes",
  dataType: 'json',
  async: true,
  success: function(latlngs) {
    var Geodesic = L.geodesic([latlngs], {
      weight: 3,
      opacity: 1,
      color: 'navy',
      steps: 200
    }).addTo(mymap);
  }
});
```

With this dataset:

```js
[
  [
    33.63669961111111, -84.427864
  ],
  [
    28.42938888888889, -81.309
  ],
  [
    44.65094444444444, -73.46813888888889
  ],
  [
    28.42938888888889, -81.309
  ]
]
```

And I get nice smooth geodesic lines, but when I use a larger dataset:

```js
[
  [
    33.43427777777777, -112.01158333333333
  ],
  [
    41.97732013888889, -87.90800591666667
  ],
  [
    41.97732013888889, -87.90800591666667
  ],
  [
    33.942625, -118.40780277777779
  ],
  [
    39.861666666666665, -104.67316666666667
  ],
  [
    39.861666666666665, -104.67316666666667
  ],
  [
    33.942625, -118.40780277777779
  ],
  [
    44.881972222222224, -93.22177777777777
  ],
  [
    44.881972222222224, -93.22177777777777
  ],
  [
    41.97732013888889, -87.90800591666667
  ],
  [
    41.97732013888889, -87.90800591666667
  ],
  [
    39.861666666666665, -104.67316666666667
  ],
  [
    33.942625, -118.40780277777779
  ],
  [
    33.63669961111111, -84.427864
  ],
  [
    33.63669961111111, -84.427864
  ],
  [
    28.42938888888889, -81.309
  ],
  [
    44.65094444444444, -73.46813888888889
  ],
  [
    28.42938888888889, -81.309
  ],
  [
    28.42938888888889, -81.309
  ],
  [
    41.97732013888889, -87.90800591666667
  ],
  [
    41.97732013888889, -87.90800591666667
  ],
  [
    26.071666666666665, -80.14969444444445
  ],
  [
    26.071666666666665, -80.14969444444445
  ],
  [
    29.984444444444446, -95.34144444444443
  ],
  [
    32.733555555555554, -117.18966666666667
  ],
  [
    32.733555555555554, -117.18966666666667
  ],
  [
    41.97732013888889, -87.90800591666667
  ],
  [
    41.97732013888889, -87.90800591666667
  ],
  [
    27.97547222222222, -82.53325
  ],
  [
    41.97732013888889, -87.90800591666667
  ],
  [
    44.881972222222224, -93.22177777777777
  ],
  [
    44.881972222222224, -93.22177777777777
  ],
  [
    33.43427777777777, -112.01158333333333
  ],
  [
    39.861666666666665, -104.67316666666667
  ],
  [
    39.861666666666665, -104.67316666666667
  ],
  [
    41.97732013888889, -87.90800591666667
  ]
]
```

Nothing shows up. I've double checked and both sets are seemingly identical syntactically. Is there a limit to the amount of data that can be loaded in this fashion?

I'm using https://github.com/henrythasler/Leaflet.Geodesic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second ("larger") dataset has multiple successively identical (duplicate) coordinates.

It looks like [Leaflet.Geodesic](https://github.com/henrythasler/Leaflet.Geodesic) plugin does not like that, because it cannot compute any bearing between 2 identical positions.

Simply filter out those duplicates, and everything works correctly then.

Ideally you would refactor your dataset to eliminate those positions, or you could also do it at runtime:

```js
function filterSuccessiveDuplicatePositions(latlngs) {
  var result = [];

  if (latlngs.length > 0) {
    result.push(latlngs[0]);
  }

  for (var i = 1; i < latlngs.length; i += 1) {
    if (!L.latLng(latlngs[i]).equals(latlngs[i - 1])) {
      result.push(latlngs[i]);
    }
  }

  return result;
}

$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "routes2",
  dataType: 'json',
  async: true,
  success: function(latlngs) {
    console.log(latlngs);
    var filtered = filterSuccessiveDuplicatePositions(latlngs);
    var Geodesic = L.geodesic([filtered], {
      weight: 3,
      opacity: 1,
      color: 'navy',
      steps: 200
    }).addTo(mymap);
  }
});
```

Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/HaQPp6PzoW9mRVcIimw0?p=preview

BTW this bug is tracked on the [plugin repository issue #9](https://github.com/henrythasler/Leaflet.Geodesic/issues/9)

Comment: You're the boss! Wow. I would've never been able to write that with my limited JS knowledge, and it would've been a little tricky even in python. You have my eternal gratitude and I award you 1 million internet points!

Seriously though, this is excellent :) Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, thank you for your nice feedback! FYI I have submitted [PR #27](https://github.com/henrythasler/Leaflet.Geodesic/pull/27) to address this issue.